How to delete the earliest commit in Git history using git-filter-repo?
i'm trying to remove the earliest commit from my Git repository's history using git-filter-repo.
Current Git log:

57e88c7 (HEAD -> oo, master) Merge pull request #5 from RianMan/test

......

ae01e9c vue init

I want to remove the earliest commit (ae01e9c) while keeping all other commits intact

I've tried using git-filter-repo with various approaches, including --commit-callback and --parent-filter, but none of them have worked."

this my script :

def remove_earliest_commit(commit, parents):
    earliest_commit = b'ae01e9c'
    if commit.startswith(earliest_commit):
        return []  # Remove this commit by returning an empty list of parents
    elif not parents:
        return []  # This is now the earliest commit, so it should have no parents
    else:
        return parents  # Keep other commits unchanged


Is it like a big repo with many branches/commits? Does it have a linear history?

Based on the comments to phd's answer, it sounds like you wish to remove all commits before a certain date. Is there a single commit you can identify that you wish to be the new root commit? If yes, there is a much simpler way to accomplish this. Note you can also use that answer for removing the existing root commit like this question is written.

git filter-repo --commit-callback \
  'if commit.original_id.startswith(b"ae01e9c"):
    commit.skip()'

See the list of available attributes at https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#CALLBACKS
Please be warned that --commit-callback has a major bug: Remove a commit based on its message content or filename with git filter-repo --commit-callback — commit.skip() skips all subsequent commits. But in your case you want to skip the last commit so it should be safe even with the bug — just skip the last commit, there're no subsequent commits.
Anyway make a backup before mangling the repository!

Wouldn't OP want to skip the first commit, not the last one?

@TTT The OP wants to skip the earliest commit. git filter-repo --commit-callback processes commits starting from the HEAD and going back to the earliest one; when the bug is triggered with commit.skip() git filter-repo skips all subsequent commits — from the skipped commit to the earliest one. In the case when the OP skips the earliest commit the bug is not triggered — there are no subsequent commits. That's how I understand. Can you run an experiment with commit.skip() trying to skip different commits (including the earliest) on a transient repository and report?

I'm trying to use git filter-repo to remove all commits before a certain date while preserving all files that exist in the most recent commit. I've used the following command;
git filter-repo --commit-callback '
import datetime
import time
timestamp_str, tz_str = commit.author_date.decode("utf-8").split()
timestamp = int(timestamp_str)
commit_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
if commit_date < datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 11):
    commit.skip()
'

I want to clean up the commit history without losing any current files.

@shawVI I saw your question. I'm afraid git filter-repo cannot do that. Try git filter-branch.
